# How to use svg component in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, svg

I'm the react developer, but I'm using vuejs for a project. at react we used to svg image as a component, at vuejs, how can we use similar with reactjs components? if someone use like that could you suggest me pls

may I answer my question myself.

Icon components

```
<template>
    <svg :width="size" :height="size" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <ellipse cx="10" cy="9.99999" rx="7.5" ry="7.49999" :fill="color" />
      <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="9.5" stroke="#F1F6FB" stroke-opacity="0.3"/>
      <path d="M8.98893 12.0241L11.0723 9.94076L8.98893 7.85742" stroke="#190707" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    </svg>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  export default {
    name: 'NextIcon',
    props: {
      size: {
        type: Number,
        default: 33
      },
      color: {
        type: String,
        default: '#FFE68E'
      },
    }
  }
  </script>
```

I am using like that

```
<NextIcon color="#fad" size="33"/>
```

thanks for other answers, they help me out

Comment: If you want to mark a question as solved, then click the checkbox next to an answer, or answer it yourself and click the checkbox there.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this stips:

1- Install vue-svg-loader:

```
npm install --save-dev vue-svg-loader
```

2- Configure webpack:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
       test: /\.svg$/,
       loader: 'vue-svg-loader', // `vue-svg` for webpack 1.x
      },
    ],
  },
```

3- Import the svg and use it as a regular component:

```
<template>
  <nav id="myDiv">
    <a href="...">
      <SomeIcon class="icon" />
      Some page
    </a>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
import SomeIcon from './assets/myicon.svg';

export default {
  name: 'myDiv',
  components: {
    SomeIcon,
  },
};
</script>
```

- for more information go to this link: https://github.com/damianstasik/vue-svg-loader

Answer (score 0):

You can use svg as a component in a Vue project; it is similar to the way you use it in a React project: you can create a component that returns an `<svg>` tag like the example below.

AlarmIcon.vue:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = withDefaults(
  defineProps<{
    size?: number;
  }>(),
  {
    size: 20,
  }
);

defineExpose(props);
</script>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  inheritAttrs: true,
};
</script>
<template>
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    :width="size"
    :height="size"
    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
  >
   // your svg path
  </svg>
</template>
```

**Usage**

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import AlarmIcon from './icons/AlarmIcon.vue';
</script>

<template>
  <AlarmIcon :size="22" />
</template>
```